# Ruby parse invalid JSON

Tags: ruby

How can I parse the following [JS object](https://www.codepile.net/pile/P7xzAOlO) to a ruby object? It appears to be invalid JSON and it's driving me crazy.

I'm trying to parse the HTML from `view-source:https://www.zocdoc.com/doctor/adelle-quintana-md-faad-2546` which loads an object called `window.__REDUX_STATE__ = JSON.parse...` that I'm having an incredibly hard time parsing. Here's how I got the code to the format it's in now:

```
body = HTTPClient.get("https://www.zocdoc.com/doctor/adelle-quintana-md-faad-2546").body
body[/window\.__REDUX_STATE__ = JSON\.parse\("(.*?)"\);/, 1]
```

And here is a sample from the text on how it's formatted (it's much longer)

```
{\"routing\":{\"locationBeforeTransitions\":null},\"theme\":{\...etc
```

Comment: What's invalid about that? It looks like a JSON string to me, at least within the context of a Ruby string visualized with `inspect`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you are facing problem to parse the JSON. 
If this is the issue, then you can parse using the json gem

```
require 'json'
Json.parse(json_string)
```

Note : Before using the gem we need to first install them using the following command

gem install json

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me in rails console. Just copy-pasted the text that you provided on Codepile

```
JSON.parse("here goes copy-paste result")
```

Maybe you forgot to wrap it inside quotes (")?